# Finding text within a string and replacing some text on the next line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file, which has some text similar to below:

```
#my-var="Group Name",*ItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/1
#my-var="Group Name",ItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/2
#my-var="Group Name",ItemInGroup2
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/3
#my-var="Another Group Name",*AnotherItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/4
#my-var="Another Group Name",AnotherItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/5
```

However, I would like to search through the document, and if it finds `my-var="+++++++++++",*` (where `+++++++++++` could be anything), then it moves on to the next line, and replaces `aaa/bbb` with `yyy/zzz`.  The expected outcome, is as below:

```
#my-var="Group Name",*ItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/yyy/zzz/1
#my-var="Group Name",ItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/2
#my-var="Group Name",ItemInGroup2
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/3
#my-var="Another Group Name",*AnotherItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/yyy/zzz/4
#my-var="Another Group Name",AnotherItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/5
```

Was looking to do this in a shell script, but my regex and sed/awk experience isn't good enough...  So hopefully someone know the answer easily :)

Cheers

David

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/my-var=".*",\*/{n;s|aaa/bbb|yyy/zzz|}' file
```

If a lines matches regex `my-var=".*",\*` then read next line (`n`) and search (`s|||`) for `aaa/bbb` and replace with `yyy/zzz`.

Output:

```
#my-var="Group Name",*ItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/yyy/zzz/1
#my-var="Group Name",ItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/2
#my-var="Group Name",ItemInGroup2
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/3
#my-var="Another Group Name",*AnotherItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/yyy/zzz/4
#my-var="Another Group Name",AnotherItemInGroup
ThisIsTheResult/aaa/bbb/5
```

---

Please take a look at `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858).

Comment: Remember `.*` is greedy so perhaps `"[^"]*"` to match anything between double quotes.